# Is there any way for a program to detect it is running inside 'expect'?

Tags: shell, expect

I want to run in a 'expect friendly mode', so I want to detect if my program was spawned by expect. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Just curious in which way is it Expect friendly? Usually a user friendly program should be Expect friendly too.

Comment: or you can make it more explicit by adding a special command line option like `--expect-friendly`. :)

Comment: FYI: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: You might instead consider just making your program *script friendly*, so that users don't need to resort to artifices like `expect`. For example, so a script can *pipe* commands into the program, or can run it with a command as an argument, with options to reduce the output to just a wanted item.

Comment: Off the top of my head, and with little to no thinking involved, you could probably get your parent process id (`ppid`) and see if the parent is `expect`. Of course, if someone wants to hide the fact from you that they are using `expect` they only need to copy the expect binary and change its name, but it is not clear what your purpose is anyway so I don't know if that's a problem.

Comment: Please define "friendly" -- is it something like "if I'm running in expect, don't colourize the output"?

Comment: or you could have your expect wrapped program check it's enviroment for something related to `expect` or you can put a special variable preceding the invocation (on the same line) like `runningWithExpect=true yourExpectFriendlyProg [arg1 ....] [file1 ...]` . But like the *script friendly* idea best. If you prog is a script, then you can just test that, i.e. `if ${runningWithExpect:=false} ; then echo RUnning with Expect ; else echo No Expect; fi` Good luck!

Comment: @glennjackman yes, avoid printing cursor control codes when inside expect.  Eventually I went with an environment variable as solution.